# Docker compose deployment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a question about docker compose. I am new to docker and I can't figure out the "right" flow for deployment.

Lets assume we have a *"Dockerfile"* which contain a steps to build an image from project source files.
And we have a *"docker-compose.yml"* which is actually building this *"Dockerfile"* along with 2 more services.
It is not important here but lets say they are, nginx, webapi (actual project) and mongodb.

So, if i will run **"docker compose up"** on my machine - it will create 3 images (webapi, nginx, mongodb) and run them. Everything is perfect here.

Questions is, what i need to do to get it deployed to production. What i have tried:

- I can checkout git on production server and run **"docker compose up"** and it will work. But i think this is not the way to go - use of production server to build projects seems silly.
- I can run **"docker compose build"** locally, get 3 images, push them to docker repository, go to production download images from repository and start them one by one. In this case I don't see a point in **"docker compose"** at all, I am loosing the way to easily define volumes and relation between images, which I can do with docker compose. It will also require a lot of manual activity, or some custom scripts to automate it.

It seems like, there is a way to use **"docker machine"** to connect to remote server and use **"docker compose up"**, but I was not able to make it work. For some reasons it was not possible to connect from Windows to a remote docker on Linux.
Before going further with that option I need to understand/confirm, it case of remote docker, and **"docker compose up"**, where the build will happen? And if I have a few volumes defined in *"docker-compose.yml"* are they going to be created on local machine or on remote?

Answer (score 0):

For my project I went with option that resembles your second proposal but bit more automatic. The CI is doing the `docker build webapi` as this is the only part of my system that is actually build from sources. Ci is also doing `docker push` to my private repository. Next step is running `docker-compose up` on production. The compose is not building the webapi it is only configuring it so rather than using `build` section its using `image`. Docker compose is also configuring other services that are required (nginx, mongo) and networks for them to communicate. Even if you have custom image creation for other services you do not require full dev environment to create them. For full automation you can do docker machine to remotely execute it. Note that docker will not update images if they are already downloaded on `docker-compose up` execution you need to `docker pull` them.

Comment: Thanks Rafal for your reply, but i hope there is another, more effective way.